# Spree - how to add a custom field in admin panel, and show the value in stores product page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, spree

I want to add a custom field in Spree admin panel and display that value in my products show page.

For example I want to add **discount price** field in products admin page along with the price field for each product and display that price value in products page along with the striked out original price.

Can someone please give me the necessary steps to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

**Environment**,

```
Rails : 3.2.13
Spree : 2.0.3
```

also using **spree_fancy** theme

Answer (score -1):

You will need to create an extension for spree. Follow this [guide](http://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/getting_started_tutorial.html). In the last step you'll see how you can put that field on view.